# Node.js and Socket.io in Phaser.js not connecting socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, phaser-framework

I am able to run my node.js server, my phaser.js game runs but I get no 'connected' console.log when the game runs.  I instead get this error message from the client end:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzhkL.png)

socket.io-1.4.5.js:1 GET http://192.168.128.184:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdMR6Ro net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

SERVER:

```
var serverPort = 8080;

console.log("Initializing Server.");

var express = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);  //.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(serv);  //(serv,{});

console.log("Starting Server.");

var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(serverPort, function(){
    console.log('Server running on ' + serverPort + ' !');
});

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

serv.listen(8081);

var SOCKET_LIST = {};
io.on('connection',function(socket){  
    console.log("A user is connected");
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Socket connection');
});
```

CLIENT

```
var local = "http://" + document.location.host + ":8081";
        var socket = io().connect(local);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your client code you are using `io().connect(local)` however the correct way to connect using a specified address with your variable is `io.connect(local)`.

Also, document.location.host will include ":8080" if it is a part of the address you used to obtain the page, therefore you need to remove it. You can try something like `document.location.host.split(':')[0]`

Comment: var local = "http://" + document.location.host + ":8081";
        var socket = io.connect(local);    

ok trying now: still no connection

Comment: Before with `io()` it uses auto-discovery so that's why it was ignoring your passed in address. You say no connection? Does this mean you are getting a similar error?

Comment: Sorry, Yes same error on client end.  No console.log connection display on server end

Comment: Same, as in still trying to connect to 8080 or same error but now connecting to 8081? If you have the same problem connecting to 8081 it doesn't seem like the problem is with your app, as I literally copy+pasted your code, made this change and it was working fine. You sure nothing is blocking connections on this port?

Comment: Pretty sure connection is not in use, you were able to get it to use in phaser.js ?

Comment: No but if your code is mostly the same as what you put in the question, anything on top shouldn't change whether it works or not. Have you tried running only the code you put in your question (with the fix) to see if that works?

Comment: Just created a blank client and tested. Same Error - - - 
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
    
    var local = "http://" + document.location.host + ":8081";
    var socket = io().connect(local);
</script>

Comment: I said with the fix `io.connect(local);`

Comment: Well given that I took your code, applied that fix which got it to work, you have something else that is causing the connection to be refused. Have you tried it through localhost/127.0.0.1 (of course hosting on the same computer that's connecting)?

Comment: Yah local host yields same response, perhaps it's my network i am connected too however on home network i was getting same error when testing :( Also other networks...  Question, did you see "Socket connection" or "A user is connected" from the server?

Comment: connecting through localhost with the fix applied still refused the connection? I started the server and went to localhost:8080 and a connection was successful to localhost:8081 and the appropriate messages you mentioned were output on the server.

Comment: I confirmed nothing else is using those ports

Comment: Sorry I seemed to have missed something. document.location.host also includes the port, thus ":8080" is included. You need to handle that before passing it into connect.

Comment: Only thing i can think is its either this machine or dependancies

Comment: Did you try the change to document.location.host I suggested?

Comment: yes .... var local = "http://http://192.168.128.184:8081/";
    var socket = io.connect(local); /////Same Error but now ( 
Request.create @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
Request @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
XHR.request @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
......................net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: You sure that's what you have in there? Did you look at the actual polling request address to ensure it is correct, does it actual say something like `http://192.168.128.184:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdMymL6` or different?

Comment: "http: //http/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdM-H0Q" wow (minus the space) - via var socket = io.connect(local);

Comment: GET "http:// 192.168.128.184:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdN0HtE 404 (Not Found)" - via var socket = io().connect(local);

Comment: You've done the same thing again: using `io().connect(local)` ignores the connect() part and connects to the same address as was used to load the page. You need to use `io.connect(local)`

Comment: with io.connect(local) ------ " socket.io-1.4.5.js:1 GET http:// http/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LdN14Vi net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Comment: What you are passing in as local isn't working. Try something like `io.connect("192.168.128.184:8081")`

Comment: You are fricken awesome! That worked, so it was some type of variable type error very weird.... Cool post that above, ill mark this as solved.. Thanks dude you saved my day!